VSCode＋Springbootでパッケージ名を変更したい
以下を参考にVSCodeを使用してSpringbootのアプリケーションを作成しました。
VSCodeでSpringBootアプリの環境構築をやってみた - Qiita
package com.example.demo;

↓
package com.test.demo;

この変更は、VSCodeの「エクスプローラー」で表示されている「java\com\example\demo」の
「example」上で　右クリック->名前の変更により変更することで、
自動で各ファイルに記載の「package com.example.demo;」のパスが変更されていることが確認できました。
実際のフォルダ構成も変更されていることが確認できたのですが、
パッケージの階層を増やして変更するにはどのようにしたらよいでしょうか？
package com.example.demo;

↓
package com.test.test2.demo;

自動でリファクタリングはできないのでしょうか？
